# What test should i perform?

Tags: chi-squared-test, nonparametric, survey, likert

I have a questionnaire with a five point scale. Differences in means is obtained. As my data is not normal I am using NON-PARAMETRIC tests for my comparisons.

Population: 1 group (Pharmacists only)

Question example:

```
Statement                                                Min   Max  Mean Std.D 
Are important reference tool while  dispensing medication  1    5   3.4  .829
Are important reference tool while responding to symptoms  1    5   3.7  .876
```

How do you test if a significance exists between these two statements?

Comment: Statement or question?

Comment: Although the *data* may be non-normal, if you have a moderate to large sample it's likely the *sampling statistics* are close to normal. In that case, resorting to non-parametric methods may decrease your ability to discriminate important differences (loss of power). If that's the case, you ought to reconsider your approach.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to determine if there is a significant difference in the average (or more generally center ) of the distribution of scores and you have scores on both questions by all subjects then you could use the Wilcoxon signed rank test which is a paired test.  If not all subjects answered both questions the unpaired Wilcoxon rank sum test is a reasonable choice.